# Set indent and width to beamer block for nice itemize

Tags: beamer, indentation

I want to have blocks within itemize environments. The code:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Bad Frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some item here
\begin{block}{Bad Block}
Bad text
\end{block}
\item Some item here
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}    
\end{document}
```

Produces something that looks like this:

[image]

But I really want the block to be aligned to the item texts, and not go further left. Started using columns for each and every block I have:

```
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.075\textwidth}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.925\textwidth}
\begin{block}{\bf Output}
   Good block text
\end{block}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
```

But this looks ugly and the document becomes unreadable. Can I make a simple command or environment that I can use like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Some item here
\begin{gblock}{Good Block}
Good text
\end{gblock}
\item Some item here
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks really good:

```
\newenvironment<>{gblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{0.075\textwidth}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{0.925\textwidth}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}
  \end{column}
    \end{columns}}
```